# SQL select all statement in a node.js application returns a tedious deprecated error

Tags: node.js, sql-server

So I went to the Microsoft documentation for node.js and trying to connect to a database and I went through step by step, installed tedious and when I try to run my code it's throwing an error saying:

> tedious deprecated In the next major version of `tedious`, creating a new `Connection` instance will no longer establish a connection to the server automatically. Please use the new `connect` helper function or call the `.connect` method on the newly created `Connection` object to silence this message. internal\process\task_queues.js:79:11.

Does anyone know what this means?

CODE:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'HIDDEN';


bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('This bot is online!');
    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
    var config = {  
        server: '',  //update me
        authentication: {
            type: 'default',
            options: {
                userName: '', //update me
                password: ''  //update me
            }
        },
        options: {
            // If you are on Microsoft Azure, you need encryption:
            encrypt: true,
            database: ''  //update me
        }
    }; 
    var connection = new Connection(config);  
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
        // If no error, then good to proceed.  
        if(!err)
        {
            console.log("Connected");  
            executeStatement();  
        }
    });  
  
    var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
    var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;  
  
    function executeStatement() {  
        request = new Request("SELECT * from tblCustomer;", function(err) {  
        if (err) {  
            console.log(err);}  
        });  
        var result = "";  
        request.on('row', function(columns) {  
            columns.forEach(function(column) {  
              if (column.value === null) {  
                console.log('NULL');  
              } else {  
                result+= column.value + " ";  
              }  
            });  
            console.log(result);  
            result ="";  
        });  
  
        request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {  
        console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');  
        });  
        connection.execSql(request);  
    }  

})

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: The error's telling you all you need to know: creating a ``Connection`` instance will not connect to the server, please call the ``connect`` helper function or ``.connect`` on the ``Connection instance you created.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes So i dont quite understand what thats suppose to look like though. can you kinda show me what you mean by that.

Comment: when i add .connection() to the instance it errors out saying connection is not a function

Comment: No, it says to use ``connection.connect();``.